# Not able to create several Edit Blocks that Add or Edit Records within one Omniscript?

Tags: apex, omnistudio, omniscript

I have a bit of experience in OmniStudio. However I`m facing the issue trying to create the second Edit Block within one Omniscript.

Prerequisites:

```
The Name of an element in Omniscript can`t be used twice.
The Edit Label in the Edit Block Properties and the Name of the Remote action should be the same.
```

I try to name Remote action other than "Edit" (because I already used this name in my previous Edit Block), and rename Edit Label accordingly.

Then the following Happens

[image]
[image]

I know a similar question to this was posted before , However they did not get any reply and oi am stuck in the exact same issue now. If any help or workaround possible , then please let me know Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to name the 'Name' field with your edit block's name, then end in -new:

(Edit Block Element Name)-New

The Remote Method in the Remote Properties needs to be 'New' which can be reused.

Help Article on this:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_creatingeditingand_deleting_records_with_default_actions_and_sobject_mapping.htm&type=5